# Strange behavior in javascript argument inside a global Object

Tags: javascript, jasmine

there is a strange behavior in an argument inside a Global Javascript object:
I need to test my code with jasmine.js, but I can´t pass the expected value to the argument always return undefined in jasmine test.

```
//My model
myGlobalObject = function(){
  _myCart = function(){
      return {
        total : 0,
        products : []
       }
   }

   return {
      init: function(strangeArgument){
        console.log(strangeArgument) //this return undefined in jasmine test
       },

     myCart : _myCart,

     addProduct : function(Products){
       return _myCart()
     },

    .....
   }

}
```

The test:

```
const c{
   empty : {
      total: {
        beforeVAT: 0,
        afterVAT: 0,
        VAT: 0
      },
     products: []
  }
}

beforeEach(() => {
    this.instance = myGlobalObject();
    this.instance.init();
    this.productWithoutQuantity = Object.assign({}, _.productA);
    delete this.productWithoutQuantity.quantity;
    this.productWithQuantity = Object.assign({}, _.productB);
  });

test(`the cart should be empty`, () => {
    expect(this.instance.getCart()).toEqual(c.empty);
  });

.... more tests
```

And my main js:

```
var e = myGlobalObject();
var initialState = function (){
   return {
      total: {
        beforeVAT: 0,
        afterVAT: 0,
        VAT: 0
      },
     products: []
  }
}
e.init(initialState);
```

What its wrong?

Comment: Of course it's undefined when you call `this.instance.init();` without arguments?

Comment: Uh, don't use global objects… Especially don't leak `_myCart`

Comment: Hi Bergi, tks for answer, but why if I take the code inside main.js an put in my module.js file the argument  `strangeArgument ` works correctly?

Comment: Based on your main.js the `initialState` is a function variable and when you invoke `e.init(initialState)` you are invoking a function with a function variable `initialState`

Answer (score 0):

Although I fail to completely understand the intent of the OP here, following is my take on the question

- `_myCart` can be a local variable because it doesn't seem to serve any greater purpose, atleast from the code provided by OP
- The call to `instance.init` can be with empty parenthesis or with a legitimate variable- depends on what OP is trying to achieve here.
- I've included both main.js code snippet as well as `testVariable.instance.init();` (on a simple note its undefined if it is undefined anyway as commented by @Bergi)
- See it in action [here](https://jsfiddle.net/randomfifaguy/w1usxb7x/27/)

```js
myGlobalObject = function() {
  this._myCart = function() {
    return {
      total: 0,
      products: []
    }
  }

  return {
    init: function(strangeArgument) {
      console.log(strangeArgument)
    },
    myCart: this._myCart,
    addProduct: function(Products) {
      return this._myCart()
    }
  }

}

var e = myGlobalObject();
var initialState = function() {
  return {
    total: {
      beforeVAT: 0,
      afterVAT: 0,
      VAT: 0
    },
    products: []
  }
}
e.init(initialState);

describe('ajax test suite', function() {
  var testVariable = {}
  var c = {
    empty: {
      total: 0,
      products: []
    }
  }

  beforeEach(function() {
    testVariable.instance = myGlobalObject();
    testVariable.instance.init("hello");
    testVariable.instance.init();
  });

  it('the cart should be empty', function() {
    expect(testVariable.instance.myCart()).toEqual(c.empty);
  });
});
```